# Filter data based on average of a column in Pyspark Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How to filter the data from the dataframe based on the  condition that salary is greater than the average salary.

Something like this

df.select('name').filter((df['salary'])>(avg['salary]))

what exact command should be used.TIA

Answer (score 4):

Try by storing the average into a **`variable`** and use the variable in your `filter` clause.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
df.show()
#+------+----+
#|salary|name|
#+------+----+
#|     1|   a|
#|     2|   b|
#|     3|   c|
#+------+----+

avg=df.select(avg('salary').cast("int")).collect()[0][0]
df.filter(df['salary'] > avg).show()
#+------+----+
#|salary|name|
#+------+----+
#|     3|   c|
#+------+----+

df.select("name").filter(df['salary'] > avg).show()
#+----+
#|name|
#+----+
#|   c|
#+----+
```

**`Using window average function:`**

```
import sys
from pyspark.sql import * 
w=Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id()).rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize,sys.maxsize)
df.withColumn("avg_salary",avg(col("salary")).over(w).cast("int")).filter(col("salary") > col("avg_salary")).select("name").show()
#+----+
#|name|
#+----+
#|   c|
#+----+
```

**`Using sparksql subquery`**

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
sql("select * from tmp where salary > (select avg(salary) from tmp)").show()
#+------+----+
#|salary|name|
#+------+----+
#|     3|   c|
#+------+----+
```